# Elegant access to edge attributes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

Is it indeed the case that to access edge attributes in networkx the awkward third form below is necessary and no variation of the more svelte first two forms will do?

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=4.7 )
G.add_edge(3, 4, weight=5.8 )

# for edge in G.edges():
#     print edge['weight']
# 
# for edge in G.edges():
#     print G[edge]['weight']

for edge in G.edges():
    print G.edge[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight']
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`data=True`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=4.7)
G.add_edge(3, 4, weight=5.8)

for node1, node2, data in G.edges(data=True):
    print(data['weight'])
```

prints

```
4.7
5.8
```

Comment: Nice. For those wondering about the reference to 'data=True', it's not at https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.edges.html#networkx.classes.function.edges but rather at https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html

Comment: why add node1,node2 in for loop?

Answer (score 2):

In NetworkX 2.4 you can also use [`graph.edges.data()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html).

So in this case:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=4.7)
G.add_edge(3, 4, weight=5.8)

for node1, node2, data in G.edges.data():
    print(data['weight'])
```

The output is

```
4.7
5.8
```