# Direct access (without an iterator) to edges and their attributes

Tags: python, networkx

Is it indeed the case that the first way of accessing an edge and its attributes below is not possible and the more clumsy second one is necessary?

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('foo', 'bar', color='red')

e = ('foo', 'bar')
assert e in G.edges()

# (1)
assert G.edge[e]['color'] == 'red'

# (2)
assert G.edge[e[0]][e[1]]['color'] == 'red'
```

This is a small variation on a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35190296/704972) question, which relied on an iterator. Does the API have a `data=True` variant for direct access (without an iterator)?

The differences between NetworkX 1.x and 2.x are irrelevant to the code above and to the present question (with the exception that in 2.x it's possible to write `assert e in G.edges`)—or so I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed the best you can do with 1.x, but with 2.x you can do better. Both options appear below.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()

e = ('foo', 'bar')
G.add_edge(*e, color='red')  # equivalent to G.add_edge('foo', 'bar', color='red')

assert e in G.edges()

if nx.__version__ == '1.11':
    # NetworkX 1.x
    assert G.edge[e[0]][e[1]]['color'] == 'red'  # edge in singular
elif nx.__version__ == '2.3':
    # NetworkX 2.x
    assert G.edges[e]['color'] == 'red'  # edges in plural
```

[Documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html#networkx-graph-edges)

Comment: Ah! `edges` in plural. That only works in 2.x (at least 2.3). I'll mark the answer correct, until/unless someone suggests a variant suitable for both1.x & 2.x.

Comment: for something that works in both versions, you should use `G.adj[e[0]][e[1]][color]`.  See the [migration guide](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html)

Comment: @Joel Is there an advantage to using `G.adj[e[0]][e[1]][color]` rather than the `G.edge[e[0]][e[1]]['color']` in the question? That also works with both version.

Comment: I don't believe `G.edge[e[0]][e[1]]['color']` works in both versions of networkx.  From the migration guide: "The Graph attributes `G.node` and `G.edge` have been removed in favor of using `G.nodes[n]` and `G.edges[u, v]`".

Comment: @Joel Hmm.. it does work with 2.3. So either there is a discrepancy between the docs and the package, or something else fishy is going on.